# mysql week function not working as expected

Tags: mysql

Im trying to group by week column and get the error count for a week but for some reason the dates are not grouped on weekly basis.

```
select date(tb1.row_create_ts) as date1, sum(tb2.error_actuals) from sid.tickets tb1
inner join sid.error_count tb2
on  tb1.error_count_id = tb2.error_count_id
where  tb1.valid_flag = 'Y'
GROUP BY WEEK(tb1.row_create_ts)
order by week(date1)
```

Here is my results -

[image]

If you see the date1 column its not by 7 days or ending by week.

Comment: Try changing `select date(tb1.row_create_ts) as date1` to `select WEEK(tb1.row_create_ts) as week1`

Comment: You're not selecting the Week. You're selecting the date, and that's what you're seeing. Why would you expect to see something other than exactly what you asked to see? You're seeing a date sometime within each week, which may not be exactly 7 days apart.

Comment: THanks..I see the problem...Is there a way for me to get the week ending date?

Comment: Also consider `yearweek` to avoid mixing years

Comment: if you use `date(max(tb1.row_create_ts)) as date1` it'll give you the last date in the ones you're grouping, but if you're not definitely going to have the last day for each week you can use `STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(tb1.row_create_ts,"%x-%v 1"),"%x-%v %w")`. Have a play because you may need to change from %x-%v to %X-%V and from 1 to 0 etc : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp, http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php